# AWK: How to supress default print

Tags: awk

AWK: How to supress default print
Following awk if statement always prints $0. How to stop it from doing so

```
    ( nodeComplete && count ) 
    {

        #print $0
        #print count;

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {print array1[i];};

        nodeComplete=0;
        count=0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always advisable to add your sample Input and sample output in code tags so that we can understand where your code is not working or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, try changing your braces `{` position and let me know if this helps.

```
( nodeComplete && count ){
  #print $0
  #print count;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {print array1[i];};
  nodeComplete=0;
  count=0;
}
```

***Explanation of above change:***

> logic behind this is simple { next to condition means coming
>   statements should be executed as per condition. If you put them in
>   next line then it will all together a different set of block and
>   condition will be a different block. So if condition is TRUE then it
>   will print complete line since { is altogether a separate block.

Comment: Thank You so much! Yes it solved the problem. What is logic behind this?

Comment: Thanks so much, that is a very important point. Voted and Accepted.